# Zend Framework: Adding Radio buttons to a fieldset

Tags: jquery-mobile, zend-framework, radio-button, zend-form, fieldset

Moin Moin and hello,

I'm pretty new to Zend Framework, so I hope my question is no big problem for you.

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.5 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.0.
What I want to do is to add two horizontal radiobuttons to my registration-form. After reading the jQuery-documentation I found out that you need to add the radiobuttons to a fieldset with the attribute 'data-type="horizontal"'. But I don't know how to do it in the Framework.

At least I want to have something like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Gender</legend>
        <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">male</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">female</label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the code of my Zend-form:

```
   $this->addElement('radio', 'gender', array(
        'label'=>'Gender',
        'value'    => '0',
        'multiOptions'=>array(
            '0' => 'male',
            '1' => 'female',
        ),
        'separator' => ' ',
        'decorators' => array(
            'ViewHelper',
        )
    ));
```

I've tried to create an own formelement for the fieldset and to include the radiobuttons in it, but the fieldset is created and closed at the same moment. (If you want to, I can post the source code for that, too.)
So my HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="register" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" autocomplete="off" action=""><div class="form">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"></fieldset>
<dt id="gender-label"><label class="optional">Gender</label></dt>

<label><input type="radio" name="gender" ...
```

As you can see: It doesn't work.

Did anyone ever had this problem too and can give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks for any help.
Bazti

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly the prepend/append decorator haven't fixed my problem (or I'm too little experienced with zend to create it in a functional way) but I found another solution:

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'gender', array(
    'label'=>'Gender',
    'value'    => '0',
    'multiOptions'=>array(
        '0' => 'female',
        '1' => 'male',
    ),
    'separator' => ' ',
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper', array(
            array('fieldset' => 'HtmlTag'),
            array('tag' => 'fieldset',
                  'data-role' => 'controlgroup',
                  'data-type' => 'horizontal')
        )
    )
));
```

Thanks for the help, it gave me the right direction to solve this issue. =)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add a prepend and an append custom decorator.

Here is the [website (wiip.fr)](http://wiip.fr/content/decorator-pour-ajouter-un-suffixe-ou-un-prefixe-a-un-zend_form_element) that allowed me to know this technique (in French but the examples are clear), otherwise, I found [it](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/07/zend_form-decorator-tips/).There are certainly others :) 

I hope it works for you. :)